# how to get the related value of the clicked button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

When I click the first plus button and save it, it shows the correct value; but when I click the second button and save it, it shows the wrong value.

How to get the related value of the clicked save button
?

```js
$('div button i.fa-plus').parent().click(function(){
        let last_value = $(this).parent().children("input").val();
        last_value++;
        $(this).parent().children("input").val(last_value);
    });
    $('div button i.fa-minus').parent().click(function(){
        let last_value = $(this).parent().children("input").val();
        if(last_value <= 1) return;
        last_value--;
        $(this).parent().children("input").val(last_value);
    });


    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on('click','#save',function () {
            
            let value=$(this).parent().prev().children('#plus_minus_quantity').val();
            let id = $(this).attr("value");
            // console.log(value);
            alert(value);

        });

    })
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="col-md-3 py-5">
    <button type="button" class="btn bg-light border rounded-circle" id="minus"><i class="fas fa fa-minus" ></i></button>
    <input type="text" id="plus_minus_quantity" value="1" class="form-controls w-25 d-inline">
    <button type="button" class="btn bg-light border rounded-circle" id="plus"> <i class="fas fa fa-plus" ></i></button>
</div>
<div> <button type="button" id="save"  value="">SAVE</button></div>
<div class="col-md-3 py-5">
    <button type="button" class="btn bg-light border rounded-circle" id="minus"><i class="fas fa fa-minus" ></i></button>
    <input type="text" id="plus_minus_quantity" value="1" class="form-controls w-25 d-inline">
    <button type="button" class="btn bg-light border rounded-circle" id="plus"> <i class="fas fa fa-plus" ></i></button>
</div>
<div><button type="button" id="save"  value="">SAVE</button></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If the save button and other elements in the same div, please refer below information , his answer is really perfect.

Answer (score 0):

`let value= $('#plus_minus_quantity').val();` references the first occurrence of `"#plus_minus_quantity"`. This is why your example always alerts the value of the first set. Change this line to `let value= $(this).siblings('#plus_minus_quantity').val();` to reference the sibling of the save button that was pressed.

```js
$('div button i.fa-plus').parent().click(function(){
        let last_value = $(this).parent().children("input").val();
        last_value++;
        $(this).parent().children("input").val(last_value);
    });
    $('div button i.fa-minus').parent().click(function(){
        let last_value = $(this).parent().children("input").val();
        if(last_value <= 1) return;
        last_value--;
        $(this).parent().children("input").val(last_value);
    });


    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on('click','#save',function () {
            // Changed this line to reference the sibling of the button that was clicked
            let value= $(this).siblings('#plus_minus_quantity').val();
            let id = $(this).attr("value");
            // console.log(value);
            alert(value);

        });

    })
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="col-md-3 py-5">
    <button type="button" class="btn bg-light border rounded-circle" id="minus"><i class="fas fa fa-minus" ></i></button>
    <input type="text" id="plus_minus_quantity" value="1" class="form-controls w-25 d-inline">
    <button type="button" class="btn bg-light border rounded-circle" id="plus"> <i class="fas fa fa-plus" ></i></button>
    <button type="button" id="save"  value="">SAVE</button>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 py-5">
    <button type="button" class="btn bg-light border rounded-circle" id="minus"><i class="fas fa fa-minus" ></i></button>
    <input type="text" id="plus_minus_quantity" value="1" class="form-controls w-25 d-inline">
    <button type="button" class="btn bg-light border rounded-circle" id="plus"> <i class="fas fa fa-plus" ></i></button>
    <button type="button" id="save"  value="">SAVE</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's incredible. Thanks for answering, I get another knowledge about jQuery. XD

Comment: No problem. I noticed in your suggested edit that you were wondering how to reference the value if the save button was in another div. I would not suggest doing this, as it makes your jQuery unnecessarily complicated, but if you must do you would use the following jQuery: `let value= $(this).parent().prev("div").children('#plus_minus_quantity').val();`

Comment: Also, if this post answered your question, you should consider marking it as the correct answer to help other users who may have the same question.

Comment: sorry , I didn't log in StackOverflow these days, I receive your answer just now. I tried your ways to solve this problem, it works! Thanks, dude, Also I upload the correct answer to my problem. Have a nice day.>.<